Vuforia/Unity Video Play back Wont display video scenes
Video will not show when target is found but i can hear the audio.
I tried re-doing the whole process of image target and video player with plane and quad. There are also no errors on the script or unity consol.
Videoplayer settings
Any help would be much appreciated.

Can you play your video without tracking targets?

No doesn't seem to work unfortunately just sound.
